# Stacking strings with nets and nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets, redis, node-redis

I am having problems with redis, the documentation is not being clear to me and all my efforts to try to make a simple stack has gone awry.

I use `nodejs` as a server and`redis` together with `socket` I need to make a list of a specific type of users the relation between them and the rooms is many to many, like this:

```
MEMBERS <-----> ROOMS
```

Several members may be in several rooms, and several rooms may have several members.

All this information was being allocated in memory, it brought a lot of unnecessary weight, hence the idea of ​​using redis to manage these types of connections.

In my code I'm doing this:

Start the service like this:

```
const io = require ('socket.io'). listen (http);
const redisSocket = require ('socket.io-redis');
const redis = require ("redis");
```

I get the connections in the `socket`:

```
io.sockets.on ('connection', (socket) => {my _functions});
```

And I get in a `socket.on` the members I need to work with

```
socket.on ('ioUpdateLocation', (data) => {
    // Send the location to the devices in the room
    io.sockets.to (data.room) .emit ('ioReceiveLocation', date);
    addRoom (data.room, socket.id);

    // Emits the location for line X destination Y
    io.sockets.to (data.room + data.destiny) .emit ('ioReceiveLocation', data);
    addRoom (data.room + data.destiny, socket.id);
});
```

And so I plan to put that socket in the room like this:

```
const addRoom = (room, socketId) => {
    console.log ('room% s socket% s', room, socketId);

    redisClient.lpush (room, socketId, function (err, reply) {
        console.log ('err', err); // prints 2
        console.log ('reply', reply); // prints 2
    });
  }
```

My idea is like this:

```
ROOMS | MEMBERS
123 | ['member01', 'member02', 'member03']
123A | ['member01']
```

So using `redis` I hope to`add` and `remove` members from a room, and`check` if that member is in a room for example X.

**BUSINESS RULES**

1. MEMBER can be in several rooms
2. The room can not have 2 equal members

With the attempts was made:

```
1- client.set ();
2- client.hmset ();
3- client.rpush ();
4- client.sadd ();
```

None successfully. At first it replaced the value in the example would look like this (the same values ​​were inserted in the following order member01, member02, member03):

```
ROOMS | MEMBERS
123 | 'member04'
123A | 'member01'
```

In attempts 2,3,4 the result was an error:

> {ReplyError: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
>       at new Command (/var/www/lb-api-geolocation/node_modules/redis/lib/command.js:12:22)
>       at RedisClient.lpush (/var/www/lb-api-geolocation/node_modules/redis/lib/commands.js:58:47)
>       at addRoom (/var/www/lb-api-geolocation/src/socket/connect.js:144:17)
>       at Socket.  (/var/www/lb-api-geolocation/src/socket/connect.js:94:9)
>       at emitOne (events.js: 115: 13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js: 210: 7)
>       at /var/www/lb-api-geolocation/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:513:12
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal / process / next_tick.js: 131: 7)
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal / process / next_tick.js: 218: 9)
>     command: 'RPUSH',
>     args: ['59c54ace9e450c004ad4c90etripA', 'E4NXUZ417M2UwUxDAAAC'],
>     code: 'WRONGTYPE'}

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you error comes directly from redis and the problem is that the key you are trying to do `LPUSH` already exists and has a different type.

[An introduction to Redis data types and abstractions](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#automatic-creation-and-removal-of-keys)

Example why you got `WRONGTYPE` error:

```
> set foo bar
OK
> lpush foo 1 2 3
(error) WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
> type foo
string
```

I suggest that you open a redis-shell and do a `FLUSHALL` to clean you databases